# Crossplatform get user directory?

Tags: node.js

On Linux I use `process.env.HOME` to get user directory. But on Windows I have to use `process.env.USERPROFILE`. So I have to use this function:

```
function getHomeCrossplatform() {
    if (process.env.HOME) return process.env.HOME; // Linux
    return process.env.USERPROFILE; // Windows
}
```

The question is, is there a Node.js native function that returns user home directory out of the box?

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
var os = require( "os" );
os.homedir(); // Maybe /Users/<name> on OSX, maybe /home/<name> on Linux and so on
```

[Docs for `os.homedir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir)